# How can i get the result of a test (fail/pass) written in to a variable/file when testing with Detox on TravisCI

Tags: react-native, travis-ci, detox

Im building my React Native app with TravisCI and using Detox to run E2E on the version.

The Detox test results are printed to the travis console but i need to know fail or pass in an env var so i could act on it.

The test command is:

```
detox test --configuration ios.sim.debug
```

So i've tried:

```
export SANITY_RES=$(detox test --configuration ios.sim.debug)
```

but `echo $SANITY_RES` only contains:

*configuration="ios.sim.debug" artifactsLocation="artifacts/ios.sim.debug.2018-12-25 14-42-58Z" node_modules/.bin/jest e2e --config=e2e/config.json --maxWorkers=1 '--testNamePattern=^((?!:android:).)*$' detox[80481] INFO: [DetoxServer.js] server listening on localhost:51067...*

and not the final result.
Any other way i could get them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detox allows you the ability to write logs of your builds. See for more details https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.Artifacts.md

If you add `—record-logs all` as a flag to your `detox test` it will save all the logs of the build, change it to `—record-logs failing` if you only want logs of failing tests.

You can even specify where the logs will be stored.

Comment: How does it help to get the tests result?